# Which algorithms does (La)TeX use?

Tags: line-breaking, tex-core, typography

People often talk about the many "typesetting wonders" (La)TeX can do because of the countless algorithms it uses. **But exactly what are these typesetting algorithms?** Concrete examples I have gathered are (even if I do not really know how they work)

- The Knuth-Plass line-breaking algorithm
- The *Boxes & Glue* model
- Float positioning (which unfortunately does not work as flawlessly as one could have hoped)

Are these all of them, or are there more?

Comment: what do you mean by "algorithm" or "use" here? Only the last of the three you mentioned is implemented in latex, the first two are part of the tex engine so used by latex just because it's written in tex. 
The first one isn't "Knuth's algorithm" it was Michael Plass's PhD thesis,
So usually known as Knuth-Plass after the joint paper they published.

Comment: KOMA-Script uses different algorithms to determine the size of the margins.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I essentially mean: Which typesetting algorithms hide somewhere entire the LaTeX system? What do they do? Whether they come from LaTeX or TeX are not the focus.

Comment: As to what I mean by an "algorithm", this is hard to specify when I don't know the answer to the question. But a lot of stuff *does* go on under the hood in LaTeX, and all of that would (at least what is directly related to typesetting) would probably count as an algortihm.

Comment: There are some packages which implement some typographical stuff, like microtype, impnattypo and selnolig. Also of course the way [hyphenation points are found](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphenation_algorithm).

Comment: so the tex-core tag is probably wrong, for the part implemented in latex give you over 500 page PDf describing latex's implementation, what part of that is not "an algorithm" all of it is code that implements something.

Comment: This is really too broad in current form IMHO. As David notes, all of LaTeX is really an "algorithm" for some suitable definition of "algorithm" (a procedure for solving a problem). I'd suggest narrowing the scope of this question.

Comment: @PaulGessler What if I specify that I mean *typesetting* algorithms, as in the updated question?

Comment: @Gaussler the problem is the same: everything in the LaTeX kernel is arguably 'a procedure for solving a typesetting problem'.

Comment: Well, it should be possible to give an overview of the algorithms, by sorting them into sections. The line-breaking algorithm is also just a collection of several algorithms, after all, but can be regarded as a unit. I would like to know if there are more of these units.

Comment: I'm note sure as yet how to make the question narrower, but you can perhaps form a *different* question that will help to define *this* question: "What kinds of typesetting problems does the LaTeX kernel tackle?"

Comment: I'm voting to leave open for now to give you time to narrow this down, but I really do feel it's too broad and I can see why others have voted this way.